# jQuery. Smooth transition between background images

Tags: jquery, html, image, css

So. I'm total newbie to jquery.
I did use jquery now, after failing with css3 to do the job.
My goal was:
Hover over #b (indsection) and change background image of #b and in same time of #a (main).
div #a gets before #b so didn't used transitions.
I did that with jquery, but the transition back to the original color of #a is not smooth enough.

**Here is the exact example what I'm talking about:** [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/2NmMD/66/)

The question is: How to smooth out the transition of fading the image of #a.
Thank you all.

```
<body>
<div id="container">
<div id="slider">
</div>
<div id="maincontent">
    <div id="main">main content</div>
    <div id="indsection"></div>
</div>
</div>
<script> 
$('#indsection').hover(function() 
{ 
$('#main').css("background-image", 
"url(http://fc02.deviantart.net/fs70/f/2014/237/1/8/indexartmain1_by_aortafx-   d7woxqv.png)"); 
}).mouseleave(function(){
$('#main').css("background-image", "url(http://fc00.deviantart.net/fs70/f/2014/237/8/2/indexmainbg2_by_aortafx-d7wph60.png)"); 
});
</script>   
</body>
```

Comment: can you create a fiddle ??

Comment: @Yunus  http://jsfiddle.net/2NmMD/66/ its already up there

Comment: Yes Brother I see that. I am talking about you piece of html and css so that I can see what exactly you are missing.

Comment: I'm trying to find something relevant. But I think noting is important that could cause problems. I update fiddle in a moment.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/2NmMD/73/